# C# - Lambda - grouping List data containing nested List objects

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am trying to group a List, with inner Lists, to a smaller result using C# lambda but sadly without success.

I got the following query which returns 8 records:

```
+--------------+----------------+---------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+----------------------+----------+--------------+-----------+
| DepartmentId | DepartmentName | RoomId  |  RoomName   | ElementId | ElementName | ActionId |      ActionName      | TimeNorm | ElementCount | ProjectId |
+--------------+----------------+---------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+----------------------+----------+--------------+-----------+
|      1378195 | BG             | 1414848 | TestRuimte  |   1279320 | toilet      |  1279319 | kalk verwijderen     |       90 |            2 |   1377945 |
|      1378195 | BG             | 1414848 | TestRuimte  |   1279320 | toilet      |  1281322 | klamvochtig reinigen |       40 |            1 |   1377945 |
|      1378195 | BG             | 1414849 | TestRuimte2 |   1279320 | toilet      |  1279319 | kalk verwijderen     |       90 |            2 |   1377945 |
|      1378195 | BG             | 1414849 | TestRuimte2 |   1279320 | toilet      |  1281322 | klamvochtig reinigen |       40 |            1 |   1377945 |
|      1378195 | BG             | 1414850 | TestRuimte3 |   1279320 | toilet      |  1279319 | kalk verwijderen     |       40 |            1 |   1377945 |
|      1378195 | BG             | 1414850 | TestRuimte3 |   1279320 | toilet      |  1281322 | klamvochtig reinigen |      120 |            2 |   1377945 |
|      1378195 | BG             | 1414851 | TestRuimte4 |   1279320 | toilet      |  1279319 | kalk verwijderen     |       90 |            2 |   1377945 |
|      1378195 | BG             | 1414851 | TestRuimte4 |   1279320 | toilet      |  1281322 | klamvochtig reinigen |       40 |            1 |   1377945 |
+--------------+----------------+---------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+----------------------+----------+--------------+-----------+
```

The result is being stored in a List object:

```
List<dDepartment> test
```

The `dDepartment` class looks as following:

```
public class dDepartment
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public List<dRoom> Rooms { get; set; }
}

public class dRoom
{
    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public string RoomName { get; set; }
    public List<dElement> Elements { get; set; }
}

public class dElement
{
    public int ElementId { get; set; }
    public string ElementName { get; set; }
    public List<dAction> Actions { get; set; }
}

public class dAction
{
    public int ActionId { get; set; }
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
    public int TimeNorm { get; set; }
    public int ElementCount { get; set; }

}
```

The list object returns 8 records with in that the nested class lists, which is good. 
However, I want to group this result on the `DepartmentId`, `RoomdId`, `ElementId` and `ActionId`. 
So the List should return 1 Department, with a list inside it containing 4 Rooms, with a list inside the rooms containing 1 element and a list inside the element containing 2 Actions.

So it should return something like this:

```
(Count 1) DepartmentId = 1378195, DepartmentName = BG, 
Rooms (count 4) = 
{[
  Room[0] = RoomdId = 1414848, RoomName = TestRuimte, Elements (count 1) = {[Element[0] = ElementId = 1279320, ElementName = toilet, Actions (count 2) = {[]...} ]}
  Room[1] = RoomdId = 1414849, RoomName = TestRuimte2, Elements (count 1) = {[Element[0] = ElementId = 1279320, ElementName = toilet, Actions (count 2) = {[]...} ]}
  Room[2] = RoomdId = 1414850, RoomName = TestRuimte3, Elements (count 1) = {[Element[0] = ElementId = 1279320, ElementName = toilet, Actions (count 2) = {[]...} ]}
  Room[3] = RoomdId = 1414851, RoomName = TestRuimte4, Elements (count 1) = {[Element[0] = ElementId = 1279320, ElementName = toilet, Actions (count 2) = {[]...} ]}
]}
```

I however can get the correct result after trying multiple Lambda groupings e.g.:

```
var grouped = test.GroupBy(g => new
{
    DepartmentId = g.DepartmentId,
    //Rooms = g.Rooms.GroupBy(gg => new
    //{
    //    gg.RoomId
    //}).ToList()
}).Select(s => new
{
    s.Key.DepartmentId,
    //Rooms = test.GroupBy(g => new 
    //{
    //    g.
    //))

    Rooms = test.Select(r => new { 
        r.Rooms
    }).GroupBy(g => g.Rooms.Select(t => t.RoomId)).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

Comment: why do you create a new DepartmentId?

test.groupby(departmentId).thenby(roomid).thenby(...);

Comment: Use one GroupBy : GroupBy(g => new {g.RoomId,g.DepartmentId} ).ToList()

Comment: @Exar666Kun I cant add `ThenBy` after the `GroupBy` statement. Also, I need some more code since the code you provided is invalid anyway. It then should be more something like `test.GroupBy(g => g.DepartmentId).ThenBy(..)`, but as mentioned, there is no `ThenBy` extension after the `GroupBy` (it is if you use `OrderBy`)

Comment: @jdweng I can't do that since the `RoomId` is contained in a Inner list of Department, so I get `test.GroupBy(g => new { g.DepartmentId, g.Rooms... })` Rooms is a list so you need to use Select again to access it's RoomId property..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do it like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<dDepartment> depts = new List<dDepartment>();

            var results = depts
                .SelectMany(g => g.Rooms
                    .SelectMany(s => s.Elements.Select( e => new { 
                        deptId = g.DepartmentId, 
                        deptName = g.DepartmentName, 
                        roomId = s.RoomId, 
                        roomName = s.RoomName,
                        elementId = e.ElementId,
                        elementName = e.ElementName
                    })
                    )).GroupBy(g => new {g.deptId, g.roomId})
                    .ToList();

        }
    }
    public class dDepartment
    {
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
        public List<dRoom> Rooms { get; set; }
    }

    public class dRoom
    {
        public int RoomId { get; set; }
        public string RoomName { get; set; }
        public List<dElement> Elements { get; set; }
    }

    public class dElement
    {
        public int ElementId { get; set; }
        public string ElementName { get; set; }
        public List<dAction> Actions { get; set; }
    }

    public class dAction
    {
        public int ActionId { get; set; }
        public string ActionName { get; set; }
        public int TimeNorm { get; set; }
        public int ElementCount { get; set; }

    }


}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to return them a bit friendlier, so now all the values are returned in the last `SelectMany`, but it would be better if the first element would contain `departmentId` and `departmentName`, the second contained `roomId` and `roomName`, and the third would contain `elementId` and `elementName`

Comment: The SelectMany is flattening the Hierarchy.  Yes you can remove one of the SelectMany.  The Top Level(s) must be SelectMany and the last must be a Select.  The Select Many is taking all the children and combining as a single array.  So if you have A[i][j] the results of a select many is A[i].

Comment: Got a smalle xample? I tried to do something like this `var newtest = test.Select(x => new { DepartmentId = x.DepartmentId, DepartmentName = x.DepartmentName, Rooms = x.Rooms.Select(r => new { RoomId = r.RoomId, RoomName = r.RoomName }).GroupBy(g => new {g.RoomId, g.RoomName}).ToList() }).GroupBy(g => new {g.DepartmentId, g.DepartmentName,}).ToList();` but this doesnt work

Comment: You do not need the last GroupBy if you have only unique departments in test. If you have duplicates than you need a SelectMany as the 1st Select. : .GroupBy(g => new { g.DepartmentId, g.DepartmentName, }).ToList();